Internalization and enrichment
I am starting with the ideas of higher categories. I have encountered the notions of internalization and enrichment. I haven't quite understood how do they lead to (n+1,r+1) categories starting from (n,r) categories. Could someone kindly explain that in a bit detail?
Thank you.

I am a little on the fence about voting to close. This question, like your previous one, shows little indication of what you have actually tried yourself in order to understand this. Your wording makes it sound like you are encountering the concepts of internalisation and enrichment for the first time, which are well-established and basic concepts in 1-category theory. Are you asking to explain all that as well?

I wanted to ask how do they lead to categories with one higher dimension.

Did you look at the references on the nLab page for n-fold categories?
